# Understanding MFCC output for a simple sine wave

Tags: python, signal-processing, librosa, mfcc

I generate a simple sine wave with a frequency of 200 and calculate an FFT to check that the obtained frequency is correct.

Then I calculate MFCC but do not understand what its output means?
What is the explanation of the output, and where do I see the frequency 200 in this output?

```
# In[3]:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft
import librosa

def generate_sine_wave(freq, sample_rate, duration):
    x = np.linspace(0, duration, int(sample_rate * duration), endpoint=False)
    frequencies = x * freq
    # 2pi because np.sin takes radians
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequencies)
    return x, y

sample_rate = 1024
freq = 200
x, y = generate_sine_wave(freq, sample_rate, 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(True)

fft = scipy.fft.fft(y)
fft = fft[0 : len(fft) // 2]
fft = np.abs(fft)
xs = np.linspace(0, sample_rate // 2, len(fft))
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.plot(xs, fft)
plt.grid(True)

mfcc_feat = librosa.feature.mfcc(sr=sample_rate, y=y)
print('\nMFCC Parameters:\n   Window Count              =', mfcc_feat.shape[0])
print('   Individual Feature Length =', mfcc_feat.shape[1])
mfcc_feat = mfcc_feat.T
plt.matshow(mfcc_feat)
plt.title('MFCC Features - librosa')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I change the frequency to 400 MFCC it gives me this:

[image]

What is the meaning of all these colors in three rows?

Comment: In general cepstral coefficients are not very human readable. It is easy to understand what frequency information is in a signal by looking at a plot of its magnitude spectrum (as is plain from the question), but this is not the case with looking at the iDFT of the magnitude spectrum (which is what the cepstrum is). MFCCs are very powerful, however, as a feature space for capturing timbre information and can be used to discriminate very accurately between different musical instruments (for example).

Comment: @dmedine I believe there is an intuitive way to look at and internalize MFCC.

Comment: Not sure this question bellongs on this stack.

Comment: @Itération122442 If not, can the moderators move it to the appropriate place?

Comment: @googledev I flaged your question for moderator intervention. We'll see what they think about it. It will be moved appropriatly if required.

Comment: try https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as for the 'colors', they are just intensities: you have a 3D array, so the plot shows X,Y and intensity = Z

Answer (score 1):

Individual MFCCs are generally not explainable, so plotting and studying them is not very useful, because it is hard to correlate the changes in frequency bins in certain time frame with the original signal. You can get a good explanation on how MFCCs are computed in [this](https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/speech-recognition-feature-extraction-mfcc-plp-5455f5a69dd9#:%7E:text=One%20popular%20audio%20feature%20extraction,to%20the%20amplitude%20of%20frequencies.).

Meanwhile let me give a very short explanation what you see and why:
You signal `y` is split into frames and for each frame you get get 20 (the `librosa` default) coefficients. The internal `hop_length` parameter is set to 512 samples so after padding your sequence of 1 second (1024 samples) it is converted to 3 frames. As your signal is pretty static in frequency domain, the MFCCs does not change much, hence the change in colors in columns is minimal.

Comment: There must be some connection between frequency 200 and what you see in the output of MFCC and between frequency 400 and what you see in its output, you see a similarity between these two outputs. There is only one single frequency here. There should be some minimal understanding, minimal intuition. That is the question here.

Comment: Of course there is a connection. The same as peaks in frequency correlate to speed of change in time, peaks in cepstrum correlate to speed of change in frequency envelope of the signal.  But visually this connection is not very comprehensive.  You can look at it as high polynomial coefficients: Y= a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 +... . If you plot the polynomial it is obvious where it crosses the axes, but from just looking at the coefficients itself [a0,a1,...aN] it is not that obvious as those crossing point is a combination of the coefficients.